# How to use my Phone as a wifi camera for my TV

Tags: wi-fi, camera

I've got a Sony Xperia Z3 phone.  I'd like to use the video camera function and live-stream to my TV in another room.  So far my best success was using 2 phones with video conferencing and an MHL cable, but I won't always have access to a second phone.

I tried using the miracast option, which allows me to cast the screen, but this didn't work with the video camera.

My TV is a fairly modern Samsung, and I also have a raspberry pi I could connect via hdmi.

Does anyone know of a way to do this without significant additional hardware?